# hide divs and remember on page change/refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs on a page:

```
header-div
fixed_menu_div
page_cont
```

here is the CSS the divs have:

```
#header-div {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

#page_cont {
    margin-left:200px;
    height:80%;
}

#fixed_menu_div {
    width:200px;
    height:80%;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    overflow-x:none;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position:fixed;
}
```

i want to have links on the `header_div` and `fixed_menu_div` which will hide them and save the state (show or hide) if the page is changed on refreshed and then make the `page_cont` div 100% wide

Comment: A webpage(internet, in general) is stateless. So, we cannot save the state on page refresh unless we save it to a database or session or a cookie.

Comment: when your refresh you page, you release all dom elements from it, so you need to persist your properties, u could use [Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), [WebStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), and finally persist data to server via ajax request. choose what's best for you

Comment: It makes it hard for me to want to help you when you ignore your previous questions..

Answer (score 1):

You can store the state of you divs (show/hide) in a cookie and reevaluate the cookie on page load/refresh.

Here is a link to help you manipulate cookies with js : w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Now, @m3h2014, you know someone is going to post a link to w3fools.com on here soon...

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the visible state of your elements in database using ajax calls. Cookies can be cleaned so I wont recommend that.
You can then use the following methiod to show and hide the elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#page_cont').css('width','100%');
   //retrive the values from database with 1 as visible and 0 as invisible
   setVisibility(1,0,1);
});

function setVisibility(header_div_visibility,page_cont_visibility,fixed_menu_div_visibility){
    (header_div_visibility===1)?$('#header-div').show():$('#header-div').hide();
    (page_cont_visibility===1) ? $('#page_cont').show():$('#page_cont').hide();
    (fixed_menu_div_visibility===1) ? $('#fixed_menu_div').show():$('#fixed_menu_div').hide();
}
```